# Material UI Potential Slow Performance of withStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, performance, material-ui, css-in-js

I'm tasked with making a page in our react redux web app load faster.

When the action for loading the page triggers we get what appears to be a small freeze of roughly .5 sec.

I have the profiler open and at first glance nothing seems to be wrong.
[Flame Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zML1m.png)

There are no unnecessary rerenders, and the only yellow warning that is shown is roughly 10 milliseconds.

When I go to the ranked tab in the profiler I get a slightly different story where I find that the majority of the time is spent in withStyles().
[Ranked Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8XQO.png)

We use the material-ui approach of CSS in JS via withStyles() and it appears as if the use of WithStyles() is significantly affecting the load speed.
Is this the case? or is this simply a case of "I'm rendering too many things at once"

It would be a significant effort to convert the CSS in JS to just CSS, although I did spend an hour ripping out the CSS in JS and found a performance improvement of about 40% although it is unknown to me how much of that 40% is due to the withStyles versus just the performance of styling elements on a page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> +90% of the time spent in WithStyles is actually spent in [JSS](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss), there very few we can do about it on Material-UI side.

[From](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10778#issuecomment-375905437)

Although, there is a possible speed up that doesn't include re-writing you JS CSS styling approach, which is switching to `makeStyles` instead of `withStyles`

Can be found out [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10778#issuecomment-472840548)

Comment: After 3 hours of switching over all the functional components I could find to use makeStyles I saw an improvement of 16% in the development build.  Not the improvement I was looking for but it helps.